# No puede convertir un objeto DBNull otros tipos

Tags: sql-server-2012

//   me aparece la base de datos que no se puede convertir otro tipo de valor //marcar el error en int codigo

```
            DbParameter param6 = moComm.CreateParameter();
            param6.ParameterName = "@ventaid";
            param6.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param6.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            moComm.Parameters.Add(param6);
            moConn.Open();
            moComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int codigos = System.Convert.ToInt32(moComm.Parameters["@ventaid"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu valor de la Base de datos es NULL no se puede convertir, para ello usa el Case When

```
( case when ventaid is null then '' else ventaid end) as ventaid
```

Asi cuando sea NULL lo mostrara como cadena vacía y no como NULL y ahora si lo puedes convertir a Int

Comment: mi problema es  cuando guardo el registro de venta  me registra todo bien excepto codigos